# zend framework skeleton application not showing properly

Tags: zend-framework2

I have installed the Skeleton Application manually. My application is kept in "D:\xampp\htdocs\zf2". I've created a virtual host in the following way, in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName zf2
DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/zf2/public/index.php"
<Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/zf2/public/index.php">
    #DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but it does not shown properly and it gives the output
[image]

and the remain ing application with module and database shows also not shows in the proper way
[image]
 but if i slightly modify in virtual host settings of

DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/zf2/public/index.php"

to

DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/zf2/public"

then, skeleton application shows fine but when i configure module and database it gives error "The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script. zend sleleton application error"

can any one help me i have waste lot of time to set it but didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set document root to the folder not a file.  The page looks messed up when pointing to index.php as documentroot because it cannot find the stylesheets.

The issue with configuring the module/database is probably a different issue, and you would have to post your module/database configuration to get help there.